# Can relative clauses be nested without particles in between?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I searched for other questions about nested relative clauses, and while they seem possible, most examples seem to have particles inside the nested structure:

> ワインが詳しい人と飲む機会がないので、楽しみにしています。

Here we have the particle と connecting two relative clauses 「ワインが詳しい人」 and 「飲む機会」

But can I say something like:

> この問題と関係ある飛んでいる（Githubの）イシューがあります。- There is an issue going around that is related to this problem.

Is **「関係ある飛んでいるイシュー」** a valid and grammatical sentence?

Or would I have to say it like this:

> この問題と関係あるイシューが飛んでいます。- The issue that is related to this problem is going around.

I feel like the meaning or maybe the nuance is not quite the same...

not a 100% sure how to translate 飛んでいる to english here as well.

Comment: `Here we have the particle と connecting two relative clauses 「ワインが詳しい人」 and 「飲む機会」` -- Hm, it's not two relative clauses connected with と, but [{ワインが詳しい}人と飲む]機会がない = "have no chance [to drink with someone {who is knowledgeable about wine}]", where the と is "with" in "drink *with* someone".

Comment: @Chocolate I see, I guess my understanding was very wrong about it, thank you! A nested relative clause would be more like 「ワインが詳しい人と飲む機会がない人」, right? Or is this off as well?

Comment: How is “an issue going around that is related to this problem” nested? “(that is) going around” and “that is related to this problem” are placed at the same level and they both modify “an issue”, don’t they? Is you question more about whether two relative clauses can be joined sequentially like that?

Comment: It’s pretty natural for a truly nested structure to have some particle in it because if the inner clause plays some role in the outer clause, it usually is used with some particle. Maybe what you are looking for is not “nested” at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this.

> 昨日テレビで見た、大ヒットした映画

映画 here was taken out of the following two sentences to be modified by both at the same time.

> 昨日テレビで映画を見た。

> （その）映画は大ヒットした。

I don’t see it as a nested relationship, though. I see it as a sequential relationship, where two relative clauses are placed one after the other.

If this is what you were looking for, yes, It is possible. However, care must be taken. Although it’s not the case with the above example, ambiguity could easily arise, as in the following example.

> 昨日食べた、お母さんが作った料理

Without the comma, the food could be interpreted as having been prepared by 昨日食べたお母さん. And this *is* a nested relationship as I see it. The relative clause 昨日食べたお母さん (with the particle が) is part of a bigger relative clause that as a whole modifies the noun 料理.

Lastly, I would have little trouble understanding what you mean if you said something like:

> この問題と関係のある、（今）飛び交っている障害

I’m not familiar with your use of 飛んでいる.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer to this rather confusing question! I think I understand it better now! 

As for the 飛んでいる meaning, my Japanese colleagues use a lot in the IT / Programming context, maybe it is more specific to that?!